# Outer div accommodating the inner divs is too large by a few pixels

Tags: css, html, web

[Example Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1L3vXT?p=preview).

Hi all, I'm trying to accomodate two inner divs (a title bar and a canvas) inside an outer div. The inner divs are generated dynamically, and have a fixed width and height.

A (static) example code follows below, while a working code example is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .plugin {
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 800;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 12px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
          box-shadow: 5px 5px 12px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

      }

    .plugin_title {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        font-family: arial;
        background-color: #300;
        z-index: 150;
        height: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
    }

    .plugin_canvas {
        position: relative;
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid #300;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 800;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="plugin">
  <div class="plugin_title">
    <span>Plugin Title</span>
  </div>
  <canvas width="428" height="348" class="plugin_canvas"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the div of class `.plugin` stretches to accomodate the inner `.plugin_title` and canvas div, but "grows" in height by 5 px.

In this example, according to my calculations, the css title height is 20px + 1px bottom border = 21px. The canvas height is 348px + 1px top border + 1px bottom border = 350px. The sum of the two is 350px + 21px = 371px, while the parent `.plugin` is 376px, according to Developer Tools.
This is particularly evident as the bottom shadow is offset 5px below where I want it to be.

Why this happens? Is there a CSS (no-javascript) solution to this problem?

**Important**: the container (`.plugin`) div is generated way before the inner divs. So I can't just set the height in the container div, because, at creation time, I don't know the height of the canvas div. I could do calculations and re-set the height of the container div after creating the inner divs, yeah, but I was looking for a css-only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:table-cell` to `.plugin` and `canvas`

```
.plugin {
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 800;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 12px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
          box-shadow: 5px 5px 12px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); width:auto; 
          display:table-cell;          
}
  .plugin_canvas {
        position: relative;
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid #300;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 800;  
        display:table-cell;         
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W9uSb/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this by setting `line-height:0` on `.plugin` and then specifying it explicitly on `.plugin_title`.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLDeL5?p=preview)

```
.plugin {
    line-height:0;
}

.plugin_title {
    line-height:20px;
}
```